# Starting my react project using npm start gives error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Was able to do a npm install but everytime during npm start command this error is displayed.

Is there any missing node modules or what?

Already tried deleting node modules , package.lock files, tried clearing cache but nothing works.

````
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', 'http://localhost:3000/' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! spark-react@1.0.0 watch:js: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the spark-react@1.0.0 watch:js script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Cedz ThinkPad 1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-14T09_27_08_677Z-debug.log
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn taskkill ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\Cedz ThinkPad 1\Documents\FrontEnd\node_modules\npm-run-all\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\Cedz ThinkPad 1\Documents\FrontEnd\node_modules\npm-run-all\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Cedz ThinkPad 1\Documents\FrontEnd\node_modules\npm-run-all\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Cedz ThinkPad 1\Documents\FrontEnd\node_modules\npm-run-all\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn taskkill',
  path: 'taskkill',
  spawnargs: [ '/F', '/T', '/PID', 35492 ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! spark-react@1.0.0 start: `npm-run-all -p build:css watch:*`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the spark-react@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Cedz ThinkPad 1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-14T09_27_08_781Z-debug.log
r.com/l2Q0M.png```
````

Comment: Can you share your package.json script?

Comment: I figure it out that you are using a very old version of react-spark (1.0.0) but the latest is 4.1.1. Try to update it and try again: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sparkdesignsystem/spark-react

Answer (score 0):

okay check your node version and if it is latest try to install the node version 10 or something not the latest. it works for me , i hope it will help